# "Unable to resolve constructor for: '"dojox.mobile.TextBox"'"

Tags: dojo

I am facing following issue while working with dojo inline template:
    I am creating the template in a html page by defining the template in between the following tags(It has mvc also integrated)

```
    `<script id="createNewItem" type="text/template">
    <div>
    <div data-dojo-type='dijit/TitlePane' data-dojo-props='open:false'>
    <div class='accordionRev'>
    <input type="number" name="qty" placeholder="Quantity (required)" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" class='quantity' data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:','quantity'), class:at('rel:', 'quantityErr')" onchange="cntrl.createQuoteFields(true, this, '{{lineNumber}}');" onkeypress="cntrl.quantityHandler.call(this, '{{lineNumber}}')" onpaste="cntrl.pastehandler.call(this)" tabindex=0/>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </script>'

I will be using this template in another page like this

`<ul id="rfqTitlePane" class="hide"
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
                data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
                data-dojo-props="children: at(cntrl.createQuoteList,'items').direction(at.from)"
                data-mvc-child-type="dojox/mvc/Templated"
                data-mvc-child-props="clickable: true, variableHeight: 'true', 
                indexAtStartup: this.indexAtStartup, 
                customTitle: at(this.target, 'title').direction(at.both),               titlePaneDOM:at(this.target,'displayDetails').direction(at.from).transform({format:custom.helpers.RequestMarkup})">
                <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate"> 
                     <li>
                            ${titlePaneDOM}
                    </li>
                </script>
            </ul>`

I am getting "Unable to resolve constructor for: '"dojox.mobile.TextBox"'" error. I actually defined textbox before the template gets loaded. I am not sure where its going wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the question contains wrong markdown, so I'd recommend fixing that so that better answers can be provided. Meanwhile some things I can say are:

- You may want to try importing dojox/mobile/TextBox module before running the template.
- Recent releases of Dojo prefers AMD format in `data-dojo-type` e.g. `data-dojo-typ="dojox/mobile/TextBox"`.
- dojox/mvc/InlineTemplateMixin looks at `<script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">` instead of `<script type="text/template">`.

Hope this helps.

Best, Akira